# Android sensors (motion)

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-sensors

I am building this android app for jogging which is supposed to measure the distance the user made from a starting point in time.

I am not interested using the GPS option (longtitude, latitude), so without the GPS option and using the android sensors only, how can I calculate the distance the device has been made as a function of time?

Comment: I don't know much about Android in particular, but you could make a sketchy, unreliable pedometer using the accelerometer, and then try to use data collected from that to try to guestimate distance. Or maybe you could do something with Wifi signal strength (again, sketchy and unreliable). This is pretty much the reason GPS was invented in the first place...so why are you fighting that exactly?

Comment: because I don't want to force my users to use GPS.

Comment: Then don't. Set up a sketchy pedometer. It will be precise enough for some (and if you do it well, maybe for most), but there will still be users that have a weird gait or something like that, or they will be irked by the fact that you were 15 feet off when estimating their Marathon run distance. Dealing with them is going to require a certain level of precision...which GPS may provide. I see where you are coming from, but I'm warning you that if you are interested in any level of precision, you'll likely be disappointed. Hate to have to break it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to detect "shake" motions within your app and then use that to determine distance (i.e. one shake equals one step, roughly 2000 steps is one mile). Of course, you'll probably want to fine-tune the sensitivity to determine how much motion is required to count as one step.

There's a handy tutorial for detecting shake motions here: http://www.clingmarks.com/how-to-detect-shake-motion-on-android-phone/25

Comment: thanks for the help, but are you sure this is "My best bet"?
I'm looking for best practice solution here.

Comment: Well, best practice for this type of app is using the GPS, which is why all the major running apps like Endomondo or RunKeeper are GPS-based. If you don't want to use the GPS at all, then treating the phone as a pedometer by detecting "shake" motions is really your only viable option.

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about here is essentially [dead reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning), i.e. using starting position and known changes to estimate current position. In theory, if you have an accurate measurement of velocity changes, you could figure out where you end up. There are three problems:

1. Without GPS, most smartphones don't have a way to measure velocity directly. Instead, they use accelerometers and gyroscopes to measure accelerations and rotations, and you have to calculate velocity based on those.
2. Small inaccuracies, especially at the beginning of the measurement period, can result in large errors.
3. Jogging by its nature involves a great many small changes in velocity as the runner bounces up and down, twists this way and that, avoids obstacles, etc. Measuring and accounting for all those changes accurately enough to avoid introducing a fair amount of error will be difficult.

If this is an exercise in measurement, programming, error compensation, etc., then go for it. If you want to accurately determine the final position of the jogger, use another location system like GPS. If you only want to estimate the distance traveled, I agree with the other commenters that trying to measure the number of steps and multiplying by the user's stride is probably the best you can do.